# a DAX formula that can give my averages for similar past events?

Tags: dynamic, powerbi, dax, measure, daxstudio

I have `Athletic Performance` data in a `dashboard`, one aspect of the data is a `chart` which shows the team `average practice` load through the week (how much athletes did at practice).

Is there a way I can write a `dax` formula to show an `average` from each similar day of past practices (they are `ID'd` by a day code: `GD-5,GD-4, etc`)

This is what I tried:

```
Average of Average Player Load (Session) average per Day Code = 
AVERAGEX(
   ALL('Position Averages'[Day Code]),
   CALCULATE(AVERAGE('Position Averages'[Average Player Load (Session)]),
   ALL('Position Averages'[Activity Name],'Position Averages'[Day Code],'Position Averages'[Date])))
```

Comment: This gives my the correct values, but gets effected by report level filters:                       
   Measure = AVERAGEX('Position Averages','Position Averages'[Average Player Load (Session)])

Comment: Small, copiable sample dataset with expected result would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Achieved with this:

AVG Load Per Day Code = CALCULATE(AVERAGEX
('Position Averages','Position Averages'[Average Player Load (Session)]),ALLEXCEPT('Position Averages','Position Averages'[Day Code]))